# Magic the gathering question about exiling a flashback card

Tags: magic-the-gathering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Cremate counter flashback, scavange, and their ilk?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8527/does-cremate-counter-flashback-scavange-and-their-ilk)

If my opponent uses [Think Twice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThink%20Twice%5d) for the flash back cost, and I in response use [Cremate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCremate%5d) to exile it, does the effect of think twice still happen?

Comment: Hey Isaac! Welcome to B&CG, I've linked your question to one we already had.  If you feel it doesn't answer your question, please edit your question to clarify and "flag" this question for moderator attention and we can get it reopened shortly!

Answer (score 1):

If one casts [Cremate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCremate%5d) in response to someone casting a card from a graveyard, Cremate won't be able to target the card just cast. By the time the card in the graveyard is cast, it's no longer in the graveyard; it's on the stack, where it's not a valid target for Cremate.

> 601.2. To cast a spell is to take it from where it is (usually the hand), put it on the stack, and pay its costs, so that it will eventually resolve and have its effect. [...]

Comment: As an addition to this, the reverse works just fine. The opponent can cast think twice in response to you casting your cremate, causing cremate to fizzle, since when they get priority after you cast cremate, the spell is still in graveyard.